# Unable to install pcaprub 0.11.3

Tags: ruby, windows-7, pcap, metasploit, bundle-install

> ```
> C:\metasploit\apps\pro\msf3\tools>bundle install
> Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
> Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
> Resolving dependencies...
> Using rake (10.0.4)
> Using i18n (0.6.1)
> Using multi_json (1.0.4)
> Using activesupport (3.2.13)
> Using builder (3.0.4)
> Using activemodel (3.2.13)
> Using arel (3.0.2)
> Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
> Using activerecord (3.2.13)
> Using metaclass (0.0.1)
> Using mocha (0.13.3)
> Using bourne (1.4.0)
> Using database_cleaner (0.9.1)
> Using diff-lcs (1.2.2)
> Using factory_girl (4.2.0)
> Using json (1.7.7)
> Using pg (0.15.1)
> Using metasploit_data_models (0.16.1)
> Using msgpack (0.5.4)
> Using network_interface (0.0.1)
> Using nokogiri (1.5.9)
> Using packetfu (1.1.8)
> Installing pcaprub (0.11.3)
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
> .
>
>     C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>
> [*] Running checks for pcaprub code...
> platform is i386-mingw32
> checking for main() in -lws2_32... yes
> checking for main() in -liphlpapi... yes
> checking for windows.h... yes
> checking for winsock2.h... yes
> checking for iphlpapi.h... yes
> checking for pcap_open_live() in -lwpcap... no
> checking for pcap_setnonblock() in -lwpcap... no
> creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR="
> generating pcaprub-i386-mingw32.def
> compiling pcaprub.c
> In file included from C:/WpdPack/include/pcap/pcap.h:41:0,
>                  from C:/WpdPack/include/pcap.h:45,
>                  from pcaprub.c:8:
> C:/WpdPack/include/pcap-stdinc.h:64:0: warning: "snprintf" redefined
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/subst.h:6:0: note: this is the location of th
> e previous definition
> C:/WpdPack/include/pcap-stdinc.h:65:0: warning: "vsnprintf" redefined
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/subst.h:7:0: note: this is the location of th
> e previous definition
> linking shared-object pcaprub.so
> gcc.exe: C:/Users/niravzaveri/Downloads/DevKit/link: No such file or directory
> gcc.exe: /LIBPATH:C:/WpdPack/lib: Invalid argument
> make: *** [pcaprub.so] Error 1
>
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0
> .11.3 for inspection.
> Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0.11.3/ext/pcaprub
> /gem_make.out
> An error occurred while installing pcaprub (0.11.3), and Bundler cannot
> continue.
> Make sure that `gem install pcaprub -v '0.11.3'` succeeds before bundling.
> ```

To run MSF on Win7/32-bit, I just prepared Ruby200.
I am unable to do much without installing the bundle.

I tried to install using the following thread:
http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/392423

I did install a pcaprub  0.11.3.a1 (own made patch as per above url) and it works as well, but when I do "bundle install", it tries to install pcaprub 0.11.3 again!

The paths:
C:/Users/niravzaveri/Downloads/DevKit/ is set, but there's no link folder
C:/WpdPack/lib is a valid path but where its going wrong no clue.

Please let me know what other information would you need to help me solve the issue.

This is my first encounter with Ruby.

Thanks for the help!